# How to store a button clicked as string using inline keyboard for telegram bot python

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='option 1', callback_data='1'))
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='option 2', callback_data='2'))
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"text: {message.text}\n\nnow please choose a label",reply_markup=markup)
query = Update.callback_query.inline_message_id.text
print(query)
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Update' has no attribute 'callback_query'

Expected output is

Print the text of whatever button is pressed

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html

I believe my case is `inline_message_id` as the buttons are attached to the bot message.

Thanks.

Comment: use Update.CallbackQuery I guess

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Update' has no attribute 'CallbackQuery' , I get same error

Comment: Understand these two examples: 1) https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py 2) https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard2.py

Comment: thanks i resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Am answering my own question just so that I may help other people.

first ,

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: text)
def get_title(message):
    data['text'] = message.text
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='A', callback_data='option1'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='B', callback_data='option2'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"text: {message.text}\n\nFinally, choose the label that fits the best",reply_markup=markup)
```

then we need a another function that handles callback query

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_handler(call):
    store_button_clicked = call.data ##call.data gets the the text of a button clicked 'A' or 'B'

##do something with store_button_clicked
```

I hope I provided enough information

Thanks,